# SAP HANA SQL SCRIPT Select where in array

Tags: hana-sql-script, amdp

is there any possibility to use something like SELECT * FROM xy WHERE xy.field in :array; 
in SQL SCRIPT? Im using Abap Managed Datebase Procedures

```
DECLARE arr NVARCHAR(5) ARRAY;
IF i_where = ''
  THEN arr  = ARRAY ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'  );
  ELSE arr  = ARRAY ( i_where );
END IF;

e_result = SELECT DISTINCT
...
 WHERE sales.hierarchy in :arr
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the **[NOT] MEMBER OF** function https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/f6/66b950e5d34f84bb5b6f125e7e85c4/content.htm to check for matches within in an array.

If you want the array contents to be the filter for a column, then you first need to UNNEST it.

Comment: I Think the MEMBER OF Function doesnt work on SQL Script.

Comment: It works in SQL, specifically in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement. That's how you can use it in SQL Script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, though not sure of performance issues:

1. Unnest the array to tbl:

   ```
   TABLE = UNNEST(ARRAY) as (FIELDNAME)
   ```
2. Now put the select like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM (YOUR_TABLE) where FIELDNAME IN ( SELECT FIELDNAME FROM Table )
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Not directly, but you can use [UNNEST](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/4f/12887c7941410d802a36c3f1a87a59/content.htm?frameset=/en/66/49b3fcc87c4a1db20648aeaed5de13/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/ed/4f384562ce4861b48e22a8be3171e5/plain.htm&node_id=86) to make a table out of it like so:

```
tbl = UNNEST(:arr);
SELECT .... WHERE sales.hierarchy in :tbl;
```

Comment: tbl = UNNEST (:ARR);
...
WHERE sales.hierarchy IN :tbl; ...

Shows an error, doesnt work for me : o

Answer (score -1):

name the unnest field.
tbl = UNNEST(:arr) as ("fieldname");
Try 
 ... WHERE sales.hierarchy IN ( selec "fieldname" from tbl )